# How would I implement MATLAB's "eig(A, B)" function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, matlab, linear-algebra, lapack

According to MATLAB's [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html):

> [`V`,`D`] = eig(`A`,`B`) returns diagonal matrix `D` of generalized eigenvalues and full matrix `V` whose columns are the corresponding right eigenvectors, so that `A*V = B*V*D`.

As I read available source code (It seems all implementations I've looked at  Octave, R, Scipy) lead to LAPACK's `DGGEV` routine, which isn't available from JavaScript.

Rabbit holes include [Use Emscripten with Fortran: LAPACK binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990243/use-emscripten-with-fortran-lapack-binding) and learning enough Fortran and linear algebra to do it myself.

Anyone know of something more accessible?

Comment: Try this http://www.numericjs.com/workshop.php?link=bf9eb195e289cf58fe226b11ff9e70d3360865f1aa1565d23990ad12673fd7de

Comment: or [sylvester.js](http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/) both libs include implementations of EVD but one can just take the generic algorithm and implement it in js as is

Comment: @NikosM. I don't see any eigenvalue decomposition (let alone generalized eigen decomposition) in sylvester.js –where is it? I'm not sure numeric.js supports generalized eigen decomposition either (i.e., `eig(A,B)` rather than just `eig(A)`.

Comment: @horchler, yeap my mistake, it has routines for singular and determinant (had used it some time back, did not remember correctly)

Comment: @NikosM. yeah, could be useful primitives should I try to implement it myself, but my linear algebra knowledge would need a lot of holes filled first. I'm hoping there's a solution that's, if anything, heavier on the code and lighter on the math.

Comment: @slugchewer, i c ant find the js lib i had used, which implemented eigenvalues, so i'll add a lib from a past project  mine in php [Simulacra](https://github.com/foo123/Simulacra) which implements matrix/linear algebra algorithms like SVD, LU decomposition and more, it is easy to port it to javascript and modify as needed or add new features

Comment: Computing generalised eigenvalues/eigenvectors in the general case is rather tricky. There is a very important class of generalised eigenvector problems where A is symmetric (hermitian) and B is symmetric (hermitian) positive definite. This latter case is easier to solve and can be reformulated in terms of standard eigenvalue/eigenvector problems. Please  explain what type of problems (or the origin of them) you are interested in solving.

Comment: @StefanoM this is part of an ellipse fitting algorithm - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22683-ellipse-fit--taubin-method- - that I'm porting to JavaScript.

Comment: It seems that you are in the special case, confirmed also from the fact that you are using `Eigen::GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver`. This means that you can reduce the generalized eigenvalue problem to a regular one by computing the Cholesky factorisation of B.

Comment: @StefanoM the truth is, I just learned what an eigenvector was in context of porting an ellipse fit algorithm from MATLAB to JavaScript. It's possible my use of `Eigen::GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver` isn't correct; I'll keep your comments in mind if I run into problems with this implementation. In any case, the approach seems to be working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't worry: using `Eigen::GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver` for a non self-adjoint problem would completely blow up your solution (and you would for sure notice it.) Let me more explicit: your choice of the self-adjoint solver looks appropriate. Sometimes beginner's luck outperforms Murphy's law!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up finding success using the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library, combined with Emscripten.

Right now, my test code is hard-coded to 5x5 matrices, but that's just a matter of template arguments.

I'm passing data to and from the function by using row major 1D arrays.

The code looks something like:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>
#typedef double ArrayMat5d[25];
#typedef double ArrayVec5d[5];
#typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 5, Eigen::RowMajor> Matrix5dR;
#typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 1> Vector5d;

extern "C" void eig(const ArrayMat5d A, const ArrayMat5d B,
        ArrayMat5d V, ArrayVec5d D) {
    Eigen::Map<const Matrix5dR> a(A);
    Eigen::Map<const Matrix5dR> b(B);
    const Eigen::GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix5dR> solver(a, b);
    Eigen::Map<Matrix5dR> v(V);
    Eigen::Map<Vector5d> d(D);
    v = solver.eigenvectors();
    d = solver.eigenvalues();
}
```

And I'm compiling the code using:

```
emcc -I /usr/include/eigen3 -O2 -o eig.js -s "DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING = 1" \ 
-s "NO_FILESYSTEM = 1" -s "NO_BROWSER = 1" -s "EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS = ['_eig']" \
-s "NO_EXIT_RUNTIME = 1" eig.cpp
```

From the JavaScript side:

```
// builds reference to eig function with argument type checking
var eig = Module.cwrap('eig', null, ['number', 'number', 'number', 'number']);

// sets up the two matrices
var P = new Float64Array([ 92.31360, 11.75040, -15.84640, -21.88800, -0.83200, 11.75040, 15.76960, -4.37760, -0.83200, 2.11200, -15.84640, -4.37760, 4.24960, 2.11200, -1.15200, -21.88800, -0.83200, 2.11200, 15.04000, -1.44000, -0.83200, 2.11200, -1.15200, -1.44000, -2.24000 ]);
var Q = new Float64Array([ 60.16, -2.88, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.88, 17.28, -2.88, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.88, 8.96, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]);

// allocates memory for input and output matrices
var matLength = 25;
var vecLength = 5;
var matSize = matLength * P.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
var vecSize = vecLength * P.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;

var Pptr = Module._malloc(matSize);
var Qptr = Module._malloc(matSize);
var Vptr = Module._malloc(matSize);
var Dptr = Module._malloc(vecSize);

// gets references to Emscripten heap
var Pheap = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, Pptr, matSize);
var Qheap = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, Qptr, matSize);
var Vheap = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, Vptr, matSize);
var Dheap = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, Dptr, vecSize);

// copies input matrices into Emscripten heap
Pheap.set(new Uint8Array(P.buffer));
Qheap.set(new Uint8Array(Q.buffer));

// calls the function (finally!)
eig(Pheap.byteOffset, Qheap.byteOffset, Vheap.byteOffset, Dheap.byteOffset);

// Gets double views into Emscripten heap containing results
var Vresult = new Float64Array(Vheap.buffer, Vheap.byteOffset, P.length);
var Dresult = new Float64Array(Dheap.buffer, Dheap.byteOffset, vecLength);

console.log(Vresult);
console.log(Dresult);

// Frees up allocated memory
Module._free(Pheap.byteOffset);
Module._free(Qheap.byteOffset);
Module._free(Vheap.byteOffset);
Module._free(Dheap.byteOffset);
```

The whole thing works quite well. At level `-O2`, I'm getting times of about 800 ms to run 10000 iterations, and the results exactly match my original C++ test code. (It's just about exactly 10x slower at `-O0`.)

Now to finish that ellipse fit!

Comment: The details provided in this answer are invaluable, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made a javascript module to calculate eigenvalues, eigenvectors, or RREF(Reduced Row Echelon Form). You can install it using `npm i @ahmaddynugroho/eig`

Example:

```
const e = require('@ahmaddynugroho/eig')

const A = [[7,3],[3,-1]]
const ans = e.eig(A)
console.log(ans)
```

That will log the `ans` object as follow:

```
{
  eigval: [ 8.000000000000009, -2.0000000000000004 ],
  eigvec: [
    [ -0.9486832980505129, 0.31622776601684044 ],
    [  0.3162277660168379, 0.9486832980505138  ]
  ]
}
```

That's it, you just need to pass a matrix as a parameter for `eig()`. Btw, here's [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ahmaddynugroho/eig)